# How to compress only files without folders using the SharpZipLib library? (C#)

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I use the following code to create a zip file:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(targetPath);
var zip = ZipFile.Create(targetPath + "/myzip.zip");
zip.BeginUpdate();
foreach (var file in files) zip.Add(file, CompressionMethod.Deflated);
zip.CommitUpdate();
zip.Close();
```

I get the following structure of archive:

```
myzip.zip
   - Folder1
      - Folder2
        - File1.txt
        - File2.txt
        - File3.txt
```

But I need:

```
myzip.zip
  - File1.txt
  - File2.txt
  - File3.txt
```

Help please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the SharpZipLib code, there's this method in the ZipFile class which would seem to do what you want:

`public void Add(IStaticDataSource dataSource, string entryName, CompressionMethod compressionMethod)`

You just have to get an IStaticDataSource from the file, and create the appropriate entryName (that doesn't include the directory path), i.e. search for the last directory separator [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) in `file` string and anything after that should be just your filename.

[EDIT] Clarification: I had originally suggested `Add(string file, string entryName)` but edited to the above method when I saw that the OP was specifying a compressionMethod in the call. But the default compressionMethod for new zip entries is CompressionMethod.Deflated, so using the `Add(string file, string entryName)` method should give the same result w/o having to get an IStaticDataSource.

Comment: Thank you! I'll use so: zip.Add(file, Path.GetFileName(file));